# self.context.openSnackbar is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have worked on the app with material2 and angular2. I have got this error

> self.context.openSnackbar is not a function

**snackbar-material.html**:

```
<button md-button (click)="openSnackbar()">Trigger Snackbar</button>
```

TS function:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MdSnackBar} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    templateUrl:'snackbar-material.html',
})
export class SnackbarOverviewComponent{
 constructor(
        public snackBar: MdSnackBar) {}
openSnackBar() {
this.snackBar.open("Showing Snack", "Yayyy!");
}
}
```

Error:

```
 EXCEPTION: Error in ./SnackbarOverviewComponent class SnackbarOverviewComponent - inline template:0:0 caused by: self.context.openSnackbar is not a function  vendor.bundle.js:61055:9
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: self.context.openSnackbar is not a function  vendor.bundle.js:61057:13
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:  vendor.bundle.js:61060:13
anonymous/View_SnackbarOverviewComponent0.prototype.handleEvent_0@/MaterialAppModule/SnackbarOverviewComponent/component.ngfactory.js:56:21
DebugAppView.prototype.eventHandler/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:86216:24
decoratePreventDefault/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:48265:53
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111222:21
NgZone.prototype.forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/this.inner<.onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:31689:28
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111221:21
Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111111:28
ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111292:28
  vendor.bundle.js:61061:13
ERROR CONTEXT:  vendor.bundle.js:61064:13
Object { _view: Object, _nodeIndex: 0, _tplRow: 0, _tplCol: 0 }  vendor.bundle.js:61065:13
Error: Error in ./SnackbarOverviewComponent class SnackbarOverviewComponent - inline template:0:0 caused by: self.context.openSnackbar is not a function
```

Have anyone some idea, how to resolve this?

Comment: Is `My Html:` the content of `snackbar-material.html`?

Comment: yes, html is under the file snackbar-material.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember function names are case sensitive, use this

```
<button md-button (click)="openSnackBar()">Trigger Snackbar</button>
```

Comment: if I used this one then following error is produce:EXCEPTION: Error in ./SnackbarOverviewComponent class SnackbarOverviewComponent - inline template:0:0 caused by: this._appRef.registerChangeDetector is not a function

Comment: The above error was due to name mistake and this one generic can you update the question with function name fixed and new error ?